# OsmDroid higher zoom-in regardless of Tiles

Tags: android, dictionary, zooming, osmdroid

My main task is to display KML with high zoom values (very close to ground). I have loaded the KML on osmdroid successfully. Now I want high zoom-in. I don't need any map Tiles.

When I try to zoom beyond 22, it hides my KML from the map. So, how can I achieve the zoom level, say 30?

Also, if you have any other better solution to what I want, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is resolved starting with v6.0.0. The release version has not yet but cut but you can try the snapshot version.  Instructions are in the readme

Update: it's been cut

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)